# React Flux stores and hard refresh

Tags: javascript, reactjs, reactjs-flux

Ok... let's see. I have a List component that contain several Items:

```
<List />
  <Item selected={true} />
  <Item selected={false} />
  <Item selected={true} />
...
```

That list component contain and state (checked items) that is saved in a Flux store and pass it to the Items as a prop. If I am in the list and I refresh the browser, the store data (so selected state) goes away (that is ok).

If I click on an Item, and then I go back, the list state (that comes from the store) is preserved (good).

The problem is, if I click an Item, I refresh the browser and I go back to the list, the list store and the state are gone (not the behaviour I want).

Is there something am I doing wrong? Easy solution for this that I don't see? I wanted to use SessionStorage but then the state is preserved even if you refresh the list.

Comment: Where are you storing things when you store them in "ListStore"?  Is it an in-memory store?  If that's the case, then refreshing the browser will cause the store to refresh to it's original state.

Comment: Yes that's true. Actually, GMail has the same behavior so I assume this should be considered as the normal one.

Comment: You could use sessionStorage and just remove things from it when the app loads up.  That would allow you to select when things are preserved and when they're not by simply adding or deleting from sessionStorage when you want the data to dealt with.

Answer (score 0):

Old question, but I thought I'd mention the following (for folk who are using redux)

https://www.npmjs.com/package/redux-localstorage

> Unopinionated store enhancer that persists state changes (locally).